# angular select inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have situation like this:

```
<span ng-repeat="personNum  in unit.PricePerson">
      {{personNum}}
      <select ng-model="personNum" 
              ng-options="o as o for o in unit.PricePerson track by $index"></select>
</span>
```

`unit.Price` are numbers array,something like [5,6,7,8,9] but each select has value of nine. I want that first select selected option 5,other one 6, etc. Also, i noticed I can not change options using mouse.

There are 5 select boxes generated which is fine, there are also number from 5 to 9 generated as options inside each select. Those things are ok.

Comment: If you want the selected option to be 5,6,7 etc, the model you are setting on it will have to be that value - `personNum` for what you are using right now. Might help to see the data you are using (1 node is fine)

Comment: No, first has to have value of 5,next one 6.etc

Comment: I understand that, I am saying whatever you have set in `personNum` will set your selected option because right now you have it set as the model on the select list. It would help to see your data. Is the pre-selected item inside your data set? if you can show what one node of `unit.PricePerson` looks like, it would be a lot easier to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question a little unclear, but it looks like you are having issues with your ng-options configuration.

It's generally not recommended to use *select as* with *track by*, as they are not designed to work together and can have unexpected results. Also, you are using the `unit.PricePerson` reference inside your ng-options instead of the individual iteration object `personNum`.

You should have something like:

```
<span ng-repeat="personNum in unit.PricePerson">
      {{personNum}}
      <select ng-model="personNum.selectedOption" 
              ng-options="o as o for o in unit.PricePerson">
      </select>
</span>
```

However, without seeing your javascript object `PricePerson`, I can't be certain what your ng-options configuration should be. Have a look at the AngularJS API for [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions).  In the Arguments section, there are suggested templates for your ng-options expression.

Answer (score 3):

Part of your problem might be the track by $index in your select...  Have a look at the plunker below.  Also, use ng-init to set a default value.

http://plnkr.co/edit/2ZN1J61PD1Ev2OK1tezg

The code:

```
<span ng-repeat="personNum  in unit.PricePerson">
  <select ng-init="select[$index]=personNum" ng-model="select[$index]" ng-options="o as o for o in unit.PricePerson">

  </select>
</span>
```

As @cyan suggested, I think you also need the ng-model to be something other than the variable in your outer ng-repeat.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use different ng-model inside select, than in ng-repeat and initiate it to have desired value:

```
<span ng-repeat="personNum  in unit.PricePerson">
      {{personNum}}
      <select ng-init="personNum1 = personNum" ng-model="personNum1" 
              ng-options="o as o for o in unit.PricePerson track by $index"></select>
</span>
```

etc.

---

So, to complete this. Look that you use same ng-model, that is why you cannot change options with a mouse. 
In your controller, create an array of options:

```
    $scope.selectedOptions = ['5','6','7','8','9'];
```

Then use it in your view:

```
          <select ng-model="selectedOptions[$index]" 
              ng-options="o as o for o in unit.PricePerson track by $index">
```

Comment: @cyan is actually on the right track I think... remove track by $index and this one probably works, although I think the ng-model may need to be an array here, since we have an array of selects.